# Is forging another's signature prosecutable if forger had permission?

Tags: united-states, forgery

After reading [this post](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/69158/the-proper-way-a-wife-should-endorse-her-husbands-check), I realized that a significant percentage of my friends and family could go to prison for forgery.  Many couples I know sign one another's names all the time, including on the backs of checks.  My wife and I have given one another blanket permission to sign for one another, and I know many other people with a similar understanding.

In the United States, is it in fact illegal to sign someone else's signature on the back of a check if one has permission to do so?  How about signing my wife's signature on our IRS forms?

Comment: I don't think we can fully answer you question on this forum because the likelihood of being prosecuted for a particular crime is an opinion and does not call for an answer that involves the law. Check out this post from the Stack Exchange folks: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/

Comment: @Mr_V:  Thank you for your comment.  I have changed the question at the end of my post to hopefully make it more answerable.

Comment: Good edit! If you list a particular state/jurisdiction and clarified what you mean by official document, that would make it easier for us to give you a precise answer. For example, the law looks at checks differently than a permission slip for school field trip.

Comment: Good question; presumably the legions of administrative assistants with pdf copies of executive signatures are not committing fraud wholesale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the laws of Washington to be typical. [RCW 9A.60.010](http://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=9A.60.010) defines crucial terms:

> To "falsely complete" a written instrument means to transform an
> incomplete written instrument into a complete one by adding or
> inserting matter, *without the authority of anyone entitled to grant
> it*;

and:

> "Forged instrument" means a written instrument which has been falsely
> made, completed, or altered

[Forgery](http://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=9A.60.020) then requires a bad intent:

> (1) A person is guilty of forgery if, with intent to injure or defraud:

where

> (a) He or she *falsely makes, completes, or alters* a written instrument
> or;
>
> (b) He or she possesses, utters, offers, disposes of, or puts off
> as true a written instrument which he or she *knows to be forged*.

In the scenario described, there is no intent to injure of defraud, and furthermore the document is not forged, because a forged document is one made / completed without authorization.

Comment: @Mr_V:  Just curious, would it be fraud against the bank if the bank isn't harmed by the faked signature?

Comment: Why would you think that signing on behalf of a customer constitutes fraud? What makes you say that they "think" anything about signatures on checks?

Comment: @Mr_V - Nothing in what you describe invalidates this answer, nor constitutes an exception.  Look at the canonical answers to [tag:signature].  The only exception I can imagine to this answer would be a statement signed under penalty of perjury in which one of the affirmations made in the statement is that the signature is being applied by the person named.